# Grails 2.5.0 - metaParams on Set?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have the following class:

```
class User {
...
static hasMany = [data: MyData]
...
}
```

I would like to get user.data on a User object but filter the returned list using metaParams like in findAllBy (https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAllBy.html).

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want to write a criteria query to do this or the equivalent with a java.util.List?

Comment: I was hoping there would be something like user.data.filter([max: 10, sort: "title", order: "desc", offset: 100]). Does this exist, or do I need a criteria query?

Comment: No, that method does not exist. You can use a criteria query with a projection, or implement the equivalent operation on the list using the various  Groovy collection methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a criteria query you can do something like this:

```
def id = /* some User.id here */

// http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.1.0/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html
def data = User.createCriteria().list(max: 10, offset: 100) {
    projections {
        property 'data'
    }

    eq 'id', id

    order 'something', 'desc'
}
```

If you end up with duplicate MyData instances, try using HQL instead. Like this:

```
// https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeQuery.html
User.executeQuery 'select distinct u.data from User as u where u.id = :id', [id: id, max: 10, offset: 5]
```